# Google+Sheet+Script+JSON+Query+Salesbinder+"Login information disallowed"

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch-api, basic-authentication, urlfetch

Hi this question was already asked in a previous post and it was answer by Tanaike but when I'm using the suggested script I'm always getting the same error "Login information disallowed" the same problem from post (72164203) I tested this Get line
"https://APIKEY:x@mydomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents/.json?documentNumber=8006&contextId=5" in postman and it works. Here's the code I'm using but it just wont work for me any help would be greatly appreciated

```
function fetching() {
  var USERNAME = 'API KEY';
  var PASSWORD = 'x';
  var url = 'https://API KEY:x@myDomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents/.json?documentNumber=8006&contextId=5"
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers });
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Salesbinder API documentation available from this link"https://www.salesbinder.com/api/documents/"

Thanks

Comment: First, I apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. About your question, from your provided document, I thought that the endpoint is like `https://[subdomain].salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents.json?page=2&contextId=5`. But you are using `https://API KEY:x@myDomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents/.json?documentNumber=8006&contextId=5`. I thought that `documents/.json` might be `documents.json`. [Ref](https://www.salesbinder.com/api/documents/list/) How about this? I cannot test this. I apologize for this again.

Comment: Hi Tanaike thanks for the quick reply I've tried replacing 
var url = 'https://APIKEY:x@mydomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents/.json?documentNumber=8006&contextId=5"  with 
 'https://mydomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents.json?page=2&contextId=5'; and now I get this error 
response: {"message":"Unauthorized","url":"\/api\/2.0\/documents.json?page=2\u0026amp;contextId=5","code":401}

Comment: Thanks Tanaike your suggestion worked perfect after looking at the script some more I notice I had a typo in my link Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

With this code I was able to get invoice data from Salesbinder API

```
  function fetching() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var InvNumber = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var USERNAME = 'APIKey';
  var PASSWORD = 'x';
  
  var url = 'https://mydomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents.json?documentNumber='+InvNumber+'&contextId=5';
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };

 
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers });
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```